# Could not startActivity from service in android oreo

Tags: java, android

**My App Crash due to start activity from service.**

Is there any way to startActivity from service in Android Api 26(oreo) version i am using below code to start activity*

```
Intent stopDialog=new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class);
        stopDialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        stopDialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(stopDialog);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i have solved my problem myself i was using orientation in activity which is starting from service and logcat says me you can use orientation only in fullscreen activity

**Here is solution i have removed orientation tag from activity**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".DialogActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/MyDialogTheme">
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Activity` is mentioned in `AndroidMenifest.xml` file.
If this is mentioned then try this:

```
Intent stopDialog = new Intent();
stopDialog.setClass(this, DialogActivity.class);
stopDialog.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(stopDialog);
```

Comment: still crashing dear

Comment: Can u share Logs from Logcat?.